# What does it mean when we declare property like this?

Tags: c#

I am using Web API to fetch some records from the database and send them to Blazor App. When I declare the variable like this: 
`public Employee Employee { get; set; } = new Employee();`, it works fine. 
But if I declare it like this:
 `public Employee Employee { get; set; }` ,I get **NullReferenceException** error. 
 So it is not clear for me what does it mean when we assign the variable with `new Employee()`

Comment: The first version is the equivalent of declaring a new instances and setting the property value within a constructor. You're getting a null ref exception without it because the property is never initialized and the default value of a reference type is null.

Comment: The declarations are the same.  The first is _initializing_ the property and the second is not.

Comment: `new Employee()` creates an object of Employee class and assign it to the property. Is you done so this then property remains null and when you try to access anything of null it Will throw the exception. I suggest you read more about concept of class and objects in OOP and concept of `new` in c#.

Comment: By the way, this was a new feature added in C# version 6.0. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-6#auto-property-initializers

Answer (score 0):

```
public Employee Employee { get; set; } = new Employee();
```

This simply *initializes* the property with a value whenever an object of your class is constructed. It would be the same as adding a line like this to your constructors:

```
this.Employee = new Employee();
```

If you don't initialize the property with any instance of `Employee`, then it will have a `null` value by default. So any attempt to get or set the value of other properties on the `Employee` property will cause a null reference exception.

```
obj.Employee.FirstName = firstName; // if .Employee never got set to anything, this fails
var firstName = obj.Employee.FirstName; // same here
```